# How to fix 'log 4 j logger' when I want run project?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml

I want run project in eclipse but i have error:

> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Blockquote
>
> `Project build error: "Non-parse able" POM C:\Users\pop\git\j a b m\pom .x ml: Duplicated tag: 'repository' (position: START_TAG seen ...</repository>\n\t\t<repository>... @135:15)   pom. x ml   /j a b m-examples line 1    Maven pom Loading Problem`

How I can fix  error?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find pom.xml in detail. but I think there are duplicate tag in your pom.xml

I guessed your pom.xml details like this.

```
<repositories>
    <repositoryA/>
</repositories>
<repositories>
    <repositoryB/>
</repositories>
```

You should add all the tags within a single tag. Right way:

```
<repositories>
    <repositoryA/>
    <repositoryB/>
</repositories>
```

Comment: thank you for guide.But I don't know programming and just need to fix the program error. Can you explain it easier?

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>